# Objetos rectangle y point en java

Tags: java, rectangle

estoy mal en matematicas y necesito ayuda.

Estoy tratando de calcular la diagonal de un rectangulo en java pero no entiendo la logica.
Como ven en la foto, estoy tratando de llegar al otro punto desconocido, pero no me dan las cuentas con la formula que esta en el codigo...
Yo se que esta bien el codigo porque es asi, pero como llego al resultado?
el otro punto deberia ser (8,1) y no (8,9) o no estoy en lo correcto?

Mi problema es cuando se suman valores al eje y...
Alguien me podria explicar.

[image: diagonal de un rectangulo]

- 

Aqui les dejo otro codigo donde me pasa algo similar. cuando sumo algo al valor y ya me estoy saliendo de mi rectangulo.

```
static Point calcularCentro(Rectangle caja) {
    int x = caja.x + caja.width/2;
    int y = caja.y + caja.height/2;
    Point p = new Point(x, y);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si vas para abajo, deberias restar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a analizar tu problema:

```
 y'
|    A (punto)
|    xxxxxxx
|    x     x
|    xxxxxxx  B (punto)
|________________ x'
```

tienes que calcular la ubicación del punto "**B**", teniendo como datos, el punto "**A***", el ancho del rectángulo y el alto.

Para calcular el valor de "**x**" del punto "B", sumas las "**x**" de "A" y el ancho osea:

```
y'   <-----> el ancho del rectángulo
|    A
|    xxxxxxx
|    x     x
|    xxxxxxx  B
|________________ x'
<--->  las x de "A"
<---------->  la suma (las "x" de "B")
```

Como puedes ver, la suma de los dos segmentos marcados, te "ubica" en las "**x**" del punto "B".

Para calcular las "**y**"...

```
y'   las "y" de "A"
|  /     
|  ^  xxxxxxx    ^ el alto del rectángulo
|  |  x     x    |
|  |  xxxxxxx    v   
|  |                ^  la resta (las "y" de "B")
|__v______________  v
```

Ahora aplicado a tu código:

```
double diagonal( Rectangulo rec ) {
    Point a = new Point( rec.x, rec.y );

      // cambiamos el "+" por un "-" en el segundo término
    Point b = new Point( rec.x + rec.width, rec.y - rec.height );
    return distancia( a, b );
}

Point calcularCentro( Rectangle caja ) {
    int x = caja.x + (int) ( caja.width /2 );

      // cambiamos el "+" por un "-"
    int y = caja.y - (int) ( caja.height /2 );
    Point p = new Point(x, y);
    return p;
}
```

Observa que cambié:

```
int x = caja.x + caja.width / 2;
```

por:

```
int x = caja.x + (int) ( caja.width /2 );
```

ya que sino, ante un valor impar de **width** (o **height**), estarías sumando un **int** con un **double** y asignandolo a otro **int**.

también quité los "**static**", ya que no es conveniente declarar un método estático... a menos que necesite uno (por supuesto, entendiendo las implicaciones de esto).

No modifiqué el nombre del método **diagonal** para seguir tu codificación, pero no es adecuado, ya que no devuelve la diagonal.

Espero que mis torpes dibujos te ayuden a entender...

Answer (score -1):

Por convención, un Rectangle suele definirse con el vértice inferior izquierdo (en tu caso el punto (2,1), el alto y el ancho, ambos como números positivos.

De no hacerse así, el alto y ancho deberían llevar signo. En tu ejemplo, al usar el vértice superior izquierdo, la altura debería ser negativa.

Se bueno.

Comment: Mis profes lo definen desde el vertice superior izquierdo, tal vez por eso se me dificulta?

Comment: En una pantalla de ordenador, el eje "y" va al revés de como lo solemos pintar cuando  hablamos de gráficos normales. Es decir, las "y" crecen hacia abajo. El (0,0) es la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla y las "y" positivas van hacia abajo en vez de hacia arriba. Por eso, si "Rectangle" hace referencia a un rectángulo en pantalla en pixels, sí suele ser habitual usar como origen en vértice superior izquierdo del rectángulo. En tu dibujo, el punto a tendría y=5, y al crecer hacia abajo la "y" (6, 7, 8 ... hacia abajo en vez de hacia arriba), sí tendrías el punto b en la y=9.